# Executing a .exe file in SQLplus

Tags: sqlplus, xp-cmdshell

Is it possible to execute a .exe file from SQLPlus?

In SQL2008 we could run a query like:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'FILE_PATH\file.exe'
```

Is there an equivalent query for SQLPlus?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has a section on [running an operating system command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1040156):

> You can execute an operating system command from the SQL*Plus command prompt. This is useful when you want to perform a task such as listing existing operating system files.
>
> To run an operating system command, enter the SQL*Plus command HOST followed by the operating system command.

So you would do:

```
SQL> host \FILE_PATH\file.exe
```

or on Windows:

```
SQL> $\FILE_PATH\file.exe
```

But note the warnings; and it's possible your DBA has blocked this ability. [Read more about the HOST command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm).